# Font awesome as a button, when i click on the font it does not work ptoperly

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

When I click on the 'x' it does not work, it only works when I click outside (id #close has a padding of 3px). I tried by assigning #id to the i tag,it does no even triggered an event. What can I do so that anything that is inside the #id close when click event will fired.

html

```
 <span id="close"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span>
```

js

```
 $('#close').click(function(event){
        if(event.target.id=='close'){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            $(this).remove();
       }
  });
```

Comment: Try maybe:
$('#close .fa-times-circle') instead of $("#close")

Comment: doesn't work I guess there's problem with the i tag or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working as expected because `event.target.id` is not `close` every time. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqmaedo8/1/) to illustrate the problem.

What you want to do is simply handle the `click` event on `#close`. Note that `$(this)` is **always** the current selector:

```
$("#close").click(function(event) {
    var $topParent = $(this).parent().parent();

    $(this).remove();
    $topParent.remove();
});
```

Comment: you are right ahmed code doesn't work if we don't remove the if condition but i got the point so I've accepted as the answer  anyway your code explain everything. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why using this condition?

```
 if(event.target.id=='close')
```

I created this JSFiddle and it works:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jabtgr9u/)

Comment: Alright so by removing the if condition it works. Actually I use that to make sure that only when #id close is click the event will happen. Anyway Thanks @Ahmed

Comment: There should be one ID AS close on the page. If you want to use more than close, distinguish it with an id number or another name.